# Share Cart and checkout pages on multi websites in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, session, websites

I have three sites like `dom1.com` and `dom2.com` and `dom3.com`.I want to share there cart and checkout pages like if someone buy products from `dom1` and then come to `site2` so on cart page his first site products are also visible on cart page.So he can place order on any site.As this possible in magento ? My Products will be different on each site so i can't code custom for that.I have searched and found code for separate carts

Comment: You can give [this a try](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2013/01/share-cart-between-websites.html). It worked for me some time ago on EE 1.12 but I'm not sure I covered all the possible cases.

Comment: @Marius Great thanks it works.I created module and test it on 1.9 for different sites and stores and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the comments....
Magento already shares the cart between store views under the same website.
The idea is to create an extension that changes the method that checks which store views are allowed to share the cart (`Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::getSharedStoreIds`) and make it return all the available store views.
Also, the reference to the quote id, is kept in the session with a reference to the current website. This is done in the method `Mage_Checkout_Model_Session::_getQuoteIdKey`. This also needs to be changed in order to return the same value for all websites.
I described in [this article](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.ro/2013/01/share-cart-between-websites.html) what worked for me on ee 1.12. It might work on other versions also.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do it with magento.

here is very useful [article](http://turnkeye.com/blog/share-magento-cart-between-multistores/)

Please refere point 3 in detail

you just need to change

the `Mage_Checkout_Model_Session` class. Copy this file: `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Session.php` to: `app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Model/Session.php`.

hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thanks for your replay.I created multi sites using this link `http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-set-multiple-websites-with-multiple-store-views-in-magento/`.I tried your mentioned way but it didn't worked.I have two sites with different stores and store views.