# How to get SID programmatically : Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer, url, session

I am working on multi store, and i want to share my cart between multi website using subdomain.

> Store > Configuration > General > Web > Session Validation Settings >
>   Use SID on Storefront is set to "Yes" allow customer to stay logged in
>   when switching between different stores.

However I am not getting SID in my front end URL.

**Is there any way to get SID programmatically and append to front end URL?**

**Or is there any way to get SID automatically append to front end URL?**

Comment: Just two quick thoughts on this topic (not sure whether either one actually does apply in this situation, yet it might help you in one or the other way):
 1) Are your customer accounts shared `globally` or configured on a `per Website` basis (should be somewhere around `System > Configuration> Customer`)? 
2) Are you in general talking about `Websites` or `Store views` (not sure whether natively the concept of sharing carts would apply on `Websites` as these definitely could have different products available)?

Comment: @ChristophFarnleitner , first the customer account shared `globally`, in general i have multiple website ( website = country ) and each country have a store views, all the products same for all websites.

Comment: Duplicate of https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54287/share-cart-and-checkout-pages-on-multi-websites-in-magento